# Validate Specified TextBox Only

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, jquery-validate

I have three `<input type="text" />` and each one has a button associated with it.

ie

TextBox1 --> Submit1
TextBox2 --> Submit2
TextBox3 --> Submit3

I want Validation to occur only on the corresponding textbox only. If user click Submit2 only validation occurs on TextBox2.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put them in separate `<form>`s and have a single submit button per form.

Answer (score 0):

I am not that good with jQuery, but I suppose one way you can do it is to handle the validation with each button click.  Here is the html/javascript for the followinng [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eMQ8r/) I setup:

```
<input type="text" id="input1" /><button id="button1">button 1</button><br/>
<input type="text" id="input2"/><button id="button2"> button 2</button><br/>
<input type="text" id="input3"/><button id="button3">button 3</button>​

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button1').click(function()
                    {
                       //Handle validaton
                       $('#input1').val("You clicked button 1"); 
                    });

$('#button2').click(function()
                    {
                        //Handle validaton
                       $('#input2').val("You clicked button 2"); 
                    });

$('#button3').click(function()
                    {
                        //Handle validaton
                       $('#input3').val("You clicked button 3"); 
                    });
```

});​

Comment: Issue I am having is that pressing button 1 also validates input 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: @jmogera - Did you try the jsfiddle? When you click button 1, it should just put a value in input 1, button 2 for input 2, and button 3 for input 3.  Do you have more javascript you can show?  Also, what kind of buttons are these (<input type="submit"/> or <button/>)?

Answer (score 0):

Insted of doing it by id you could have a class. such as textbox on the text boxes then you could do

Javascript

```
$(document).on('click', '.textbox', aFunction);

function aFunction(event){
   var text = $(this).prev().val();
   //validation, text is the text of the box.
}​
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="input1" /><button class='textbox' id="button1">button 1</button><br/>

<input type="text" id="input2"/><button class='textbox' id="button2"> button 2</button><br/>

<input type="text" id="input3"/><button id="button3" class='textbox'>button 3</button>​
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FERMIS/zE6uK/1/