# Form appears to be skipping validation?

Tags: jquery, validation

It may be ugly ass programming, and a scary method of validation, but that doesn't excuse its failure to work... or maybe it does... meh... advice anyone?

The khodes are here: http://jsfiddle.net/wr3yB/

The annoying thing is, the form is submitting, how can I stop the form from submitting if the validation passes AND fails? I thought it was done by adding `return false;` to the forms `onsubmit` attrib?

I've checked in Firebug and I'm not getting any errors back.

I have this identical validation working on two other test websites, but somehow can't get it working on this third test site (I'm self teaching).

Any guidance would be brilliant - thanks overflowers!

Comment: You have to post relevant code in question, not just post a jsfiddle link. BTW, check your console. Don't wrap code in loader method in jsfiddle, use "No wrap ...". And then don't use ID selector to target element without any ID set

Comment: Yeah I've had a mad hour, this question is redundant. I missed all of my `id` attributes and simply flopped at every hurdle. Sorry SO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please add id to each input and then see what happens you have not added id to your each element and you are making use of it**

Ask me if you need a more help

1. There is no lblerror in your html
2. `$("#BillingFirstnames")` Where is billingfirstnames id???

Please check it and then make use of it

I am adding some demos here [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/winstonion/5RrGa/)

Refer this link also [Validate Specified TextBox Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266989/validate-specified-textbox-only)

And before posting errors here check your console debug your jquery.....

Comment: 1. My fault, it exists in my code but I didn't add it to JSFiddle, sorry! 2. your spot on, this was my problem, +1. I'm very sorry about my shocking post...